# Используют ли крупные компьютерные игры готовые БД или свои самописные?

Tags: разработка-игр, база-данных

Используют ли крупные компьютерные игры готовые БД (`Oracle`, `MS SQL Server`, `MySQL` и т.д.) или свои самописные?

Вопрос может быть странный, но вдруг я зря парюсь с бд (я пытаюсь научиться работать с БД на `C++`) и готовые БД используют в программах, где действительно надо много хранить однородной информации.

Comment: т.е. по вашему `"готовые БД(Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL и т.д.)"` недостойны быть использоваными в игрострое?

Comment: Я хочу лишь узнать, что используют в игрострое.

Comment: то, что сами не пишут собственные, гарантирую на 95%

Comment: сбербанк вот использовал в своих играх оракл, терь ищет причины сбоя. лучше бы свою субд написали =)))

Comment: Ага, и клиент с фамилией DROP снесет все базы...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Везде, где только возможно, и не только при разработке игр, используют готовые базы данных. Потому что разработка готовой качественной базы данных с нуля - это деньги, зачастую превосходящие по стоимости собственно разработку самой игры. Нет никакого смысла делать новую базу, когда на рынке существует большое количество готовых качественных продуктов. Дешевле взять бесплатную (или в ряде случаев платную). Для встраиваемых решений обычно пользуют SQLite, для серверных MySQL (потому что они самые распространенные и по ним бесплатную поддержку легче получить).

Comment: А какую БД лучше использовать новичку( в плане работы с БД через API в своих программах) для создания небольших программ? Чтобы проще, больше документации, сайтов/форумов с информацией по этой бд и т.д.
И чтобы по возможности не надо было пользователю моей программы устанавливать БД, как это происходит в играх, где вроде не требуют установку каких-нибудь зависимостей с БД.
В вики нашел:
Встраиваемая СУБД — СУБД, которая может поставляться как составная часть некоторого программного продукта, не требуя процедуры самостоятельной установки.
Это то, что я имел ввиду? Или я путаю.

Comment: Если это база данных SQL, то практической разницы для новичка нет, какую использовать, почти наверняка работа с базой будет строиться через API драйвера базы данных, который предоставляет платформа разработки: ORM и т.п.